# Use yq4 to move everything under one key to another path in the yaml

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yaml of the following format:

```
car_facts:
 colour: 'red'
 spec: 
   tyres: 4
vehicles: 
  tractor:
    speed: 'slow'
  car:
    speed: 'fast'
```

I'm looking for a yq4 command that will move everything
under `car_facts` inplace to a new field in the yaml (`car`). Ideally, it would remove the exisiting field too (although this could be done using the delete operator in a follow-up command). So the target state would be:

```
vehicles: 
  tractor:
    speed: 'slow'
  car:
    speed: 'fast'
    colour: 'red'
    spec: 
      tyres: 4
```

As with this example, the fields under the original key may be nested. In my case, there is no chance of path of the original keys existing under the destination.

I've looked through the [docs](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators) but haven't seen an example for this specific case.

I've tried `yq4 -- eval --inplace '.car_facts.[] +=.vehicles.car'` but that returns `Error: Maps not yet supported for addition`.

Comment: The `.car` type in your YAML is `map` type. Go yq does not support addition to maps yet.

Comment: Right okay, so addition is the right way to go about this but it's not supported yet? There's not a way with `merge` or some other operator to achieve what I want?

Comment: It comes down to operation on a map, so I guess mikefarah/yq won't support it. Can you use Python yq? - https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet supported in [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) implementation yet, as addition or merge operations on `map` types is not available.

But [Python yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) supports it out of the box, as the underlying `jq` supports the operation on JSON type. Since this `yq` is just a wrapper over `jq`, all the operations are performed on the JSON with jq and converted back to YAML. So something like below should work

```sh
yq -Y --in-place '.vehicles.car += .car_facts | del(.car_facts)'  yaml
```

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible to do using the new `with` operator, added in version 4.13.0.

https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/with

###### sample.yml

```yaml
car_facts:
 colour: 'red'
 spec: 
   tyres: 4
vehicles: 
  tractor:
    speed: 'slow'
  car:
    speed: 'fast'
```

###### command

```sh
yq4 '{"vehicles":.vehicles} as $root |
     {"car":.car_facts} as $car |
     with($root.vehicles; . |= . *+ $car) |
     $root' sample.yml
```

1. First, create a new `$root` variable, containing the original `vehicles` map.
2. Then, create a new `$car` variable, containing the original `car_facts` map.
3. Then, merge the `$car` variable into the `$root.vehicles` map.
4. Finally, output the merged `$root` variable.

###### output

```yaml
vehicles:
  tractor:
    speed: 'slow'
  car:
    speed: 'fast'
    colour: 'red'
    spec:
      tyres: 4
```